# Match Lookup in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have the following 2 data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'identifier': ['1','2','3'],
    'wait times k': [12,13,14]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'identifier': ['2','4','3','6'],
'bc': [10,33,50,30]
```

})

I want to add a new column to df2 where it contains  'wait times k' in df1 matched based on the identifiers.

Desired Output:

```
identifier  bc  wait times k
0   2      10      13
1   4      33      Nan
2   3      50      14
3   6      30      Nan
```

Comment: `df2.merge(df1, how='left')`

Comment: what if df2 has more than one column? for instance, df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'identifier': ['2','4','3','6'],
    'amount': [100,330,50,30]
})

Comment: It doesn't matter. It should work the same.

Comment: Can I only add df1['wait times k'] instead of the whole dt1? In your code when I replace df1 with df1['wait times k'] it returns this error: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: You need to add the `identifier` column as well. at the  minimum `df2.merge(df1[['identifier', 'wait times k']], how='left')`.